# Why does patch not find this file?

Tags: linux, file, patch, u-boot

I would like to apply a patch to the u-boot sources but some how, Linux doesn't let me. What I have:

```
reg@ubuntu:~/NextGen/trunk/FW/thirdparty/u-boot$ patch -p1 < ../u-boot/u-boot-2013.01-wr.patch 
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -uNr u-boot-2013.01/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c u-boot-2013.01.modified/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c
|--- u-boot-2013.01/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c 2013-01-15 13:47:42.000000000 -0800
|+++ u-boot-2013.01.modified/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c        2013-05-16 10:58:08.973906692 -0700
--------------------------
File to patch: ^C
reg@ubuntu:~/NextGen/trunk/FW/thirdparty/u-boot$ ls -l u-boot-2013.01/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg 16745 Jan 15  2013 u-boot-2013.01/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c
reg@ubuntu:~/NextGen/trunk/FW/thirdparty/u-boot$
```

So why can it not find the file when it's perfectly at the right location? What's going on here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are three file paths involved here:

- The patch's original file: `u-boot-2013.01/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c`
- The patch's target file: `u-boot-2013.01.modified/arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c`
- The stripped target file due to `-p1`: `arch/powerpc/cpu/mpc85xx/cpu_init.c`

Patch looks for the stripped target file, and it doesn't exist.

`cd u-boot-2013.01` and then `patch -p1 < ../../u-boot/u-boot-2013.01-wr.patch`, and you should have more luck.

Comment: Or instead of `cd`ing, just switch to `-p0`. What brought me here is that without `-p` it seems to ignore path.

Comment: `-p0` does indeed work, and in this case `patch` will look in both `u-boot-2013.01` and `u-boot-2013.01.modified` (in that order) for the file to patch. Neat.