# When applying RT patch get "can't find file to patch at input line 5"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, real-time

I am trying to install RT kernel on my Ubuntu 18 laptop to work with very high feedback rate. This is my first time attempting something similar and I have no idea what I am doing. (Sorry)

I am following instructions from [here](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup)
I dowloaded these files: `patches-5.4.193-rt74.tar.xz` and `patch-5.4.193-rt74.patch.xz`.
Then unpacked `patches-5.4.193-rt74.tar.xz` according to instructions like this:

```
xz -cd patches-5.4.193-rt74.tar.xz | tar xvf -
```

Now my folder looks like this:

```
patch-5.4.193-rt74.patch.xz  patches  patches-5.4.193-rt74.tar.xz
```

I got folder `patches` which contains a lot of files with extension ".patch". According to the instruction I should navigate into the folder:

```
cd patches
```

Finally, I attempt to apply patch:

```
xzcat ../patch-5.4.193-rt74.patch.xz | patch -p1
```

And get the following message:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/Documentation/RCU/Design/Expedited-Grace-Periods/Expedited-Grace-Periods.html b/Documentation/RCU/Design/Expedited-Grace-Periods/Expedited-Grace-Periods.html
|index 57300db4b5ff..31c99382994e 100644
|--- a/Documentation/RCU/Design/Expedited-Grace-Periods/Expedited-Grace-Periods.html
|+++ b/Documentation/RCU/Design/Expedited-Grace-Periods/Expedited-Grace-Periods.html
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646643/why-does-patch-not-find-this-file) issue, but I don't know how to apply it to my case. I tried to use `-p0` instead of `-p1` and tried to run the command without the option, but it doesn't help. I read the manual `man patch`, but it didn't help me to solve the issue

I also tried the same procedure with older versions, the only difference was that it sometimes was looking not for `Documentation/RCU/Design/Expedited-Grace-Periods/Expedited-Grace-Periods.html` but some other files

Please explain what I am doing wrong, or direct me to a material I can learn from

I am not sure if tags I chose are relevant, feel free to correct me

---

So in the end my folder looks like this:

- **rt_kernel_build**

  - patch-5.4.193-rt74.patch.xz
  - **patches**

    - 0001-lib-smp_processor_id-Don-t-use-cpumask_equal.patch
    - ...
  - patches-5.4.193-rt74.tar.xz

I call `xzcat ../patch-5.4.193-rt74.patch.xz | patch -p1` in **patches** folder

Comment: You need to run the patch command from the kernel source top directory

Comment: @YannDroneaud how is it?